# GWT and async file upload - help

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload, io

I am wondering is it possible to upload files with GWT but in an async way? Not sending the whole form but to send a file from files list? Can I use apache HttpComponents lib with GWT? IO lib is not supported so there should be something else? I couldn't find any tutorials in that direction. So any code snippets will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [gwtupload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/).